# Query parameters in Flask route

Tags: python, flask

I have an existing route in my flask application that looks like this:

```
@app.route('/<bucket_name>', methods=['GET'])
def list_objects(bucket_name):
    # many lines of awesome code here
    return 'a cool list of stuff'
```

Now I want to detect whether the query parameter `location` was pass to this same path. The parameter will not have a value : `/foo?location`.

Does flask allow me to setup a different route for this? I would prefer to not pollute my existing route with query parameter detection. I tried to add the route below, but it didn't work. My `location` requests get routed to the existing `list_objects` method

```
@app.route('/<bucket_name>?location', methods=['GET'])
def get_bucket_location(bucket_name):
    return 'bingo'
```

**Note:** I know how to read query parameters from my original route method. I am asking if there is a different way, especially in light of the fact that my query params will not have values. I need to detect the presence of a bunch of these types of params, and separate methods would be cleaner.

Comment: *"Does flask allow me to setup a different route for this?"* - no, the query string isn't part of the routing.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It seems to me that the duplicate you've picked isn't really a duplicate (the other question doesn't address whether it's possible to make routing depend upon the query string) and that your comment ought to be an *answer* so it can be exposed to voting and commentary and so you or someone else can edit in some sort of supporting evidence like a quotation from the docs. As it is, you've basically answered in the comments and then closed as a duplicate of what's fundamentally a different question.